# Marketing Cloud-Data Extension Update through REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, rest

I am trying to make an api call from a Drupal based website to MC to update a data extension,Is there any limitation I should be aware of,like each of the insert calls would count as a single api call ?How it would fare if the daily registration volume is more than 1K.

Thanks in advance,
Monomit

Answer (score 1):

There are no hard limits on REST API calls to Marketing Cloud, other than 4MB size limit of each payload, [mentioned here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm)

You should be more than fine, having 1K calls over the course of 24 hours.

Brgds
Lukas